# Applescript how to move files from 1 folder to another. Can’t make into type integer Error

Tags: file, applescript, move, automator

I am trying to move files from 1 folder to a certain folder if they have a specific name. The listOfFiles are the files to be moved.

I am getting an error cant make Can’t make {\"file1.rtf\", \"file2.rtf\", \"file3.rtf\"} into type integer

I haven't made the condition to check the name yet. first trying to just move the files.

```
 set listOfFiles to {"file1.rtf", "file2.rtf","file3.rtf"}


tell application "Finder"
   set sourceFolder to ((path to desktop) & "moveTest1") as string as alias
   set goFolder to ((path to desktop) & "moveTest2") as string as alias
   set goFiles to the name of every file of sourceFolder


   repeat with i from 1 to the count of goFiles

    if goFiles = listOfFiles then
        move file goFiles to folder goFolder

    end if

    end repeat

end tell
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't specify a list of strings (`goFiles`) with a single `file` specifier.

Assuming you want to copy all files from folder `moveTest1` to folder `moveTest2` whose file names are in `listOfFiles` you can filter those files in one line:

```
set goFiles to every file of sourceFolder whose name is in listOfFiles
```

Since the desktop folder is the root folder of the `Finder` you don't need to specify the desktop folder explicitly.

```
set listOfFiles to {"file1.rtf", "file2.rtf", "file3.rtf"}
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to folder "moveTest1"
    set goFolder to folder "moveTest2"
    set goFiles to every file of sourceFolder whose name is in listOfFiles
    move goFiles to goFolder

end tell
```

Actually you can write the `move` operation in a single line

```
tell application "Finder" to move (every file of folder "moveTest1" whose name is in listOfFiles) to folder "moveTest2"
```

Comment: Wow this was much easier than I thought. Really appreciate it thanks!